# vb.net Convert.ToDecimal Not working

Tags: vb.net, decimal

I am writing a program that reads gps coordinates. I get gps coordinates in a string format like so:

42,9659
 15,3167

I then want to convert these strings to DECIMALS. On my development PC it works fine, but as soon as I put the software on another PC it doesn't convert to decimal. It outputs the value without the comma, like so:

429659
 153167

Heres my code:

```
gpsLatDecimalString = gpsData(2).Substring(2, gpsData(2).Length - 2).Replace(".", ",")
gpsLongDecimalString = gpsData(4).Substring(3, gpsData(4).Length - 3).Replace(".", ",")

'LAT: 25.69953
'LONG: 28.23881

gpsLatDecimal = System.Convert.ToDecimal(gpsLatDecimalString)
gpsLongDecimal = System.Convert.ToDecimal(gpsLongDecimalString)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you get the coordinates in the form XXXXX(point)YYYYY and this could be a problem in PC with OS configured for different cultures.

Do not try to replace the point with a comma, use instead the appropriate `IFormatProvider` in the call to `Convert.ToDecimal`

```
gpsLatDecimalString = gpsData(2).Substring(2, gpsData(2).Length - 2)
gpsLongDecimalString = gpsData(4).Substring(3, gpsData(4).Length - 3)

gpsLatDecimal = Convert.ToDecimal(gpsLatDecimalString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
gpsLongDecimal = Convert.ToDecimal(gpsLongDecimalString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Now, on your PC (probably configured with comma as a decimal separator), the converter is informed to use the `InvariantCulture` to understand the string while, on the other PC with the point configured as decimal separator, this is the default and the `CultureInfo` parameter has no effect.